# Why is the global string getting empty at every call?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Take a look at this code.

```
 Label lb=new Label();
 string prev="val";
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    prev = "temp";
    lbl.ID =prev;
    lbl.Text =prev;
    Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
 }
```

I had break point at start of **button3** event. I see that the value in prev again changed to *'val'* everytime the button event is fired. Isn't it has to be *'temp'*?

Comment: Considering, you have 5 lines in your code. Now trace it, after executing first line, prev is "val". On click of button3, breakpoint hits at line 3 where the prev val is same "val". On executing line 4, prev var will change to "temp". Next time, when you execute the application again, prev is "val". 
I hopt, this would be helpful to you.

Comment: @Rahul : tried checking 10+ times.

Comment: Because every time the page reloads `prev` is declared and set to "val".  Code like this is not persisted across page reloads.

Comment: lbl is another label?What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Updated it!

Comment: Panel is updating previous label on every call.

Comment: Based on your code, no matter if the prev is persisted across calls or not, after click, the label value will be `"temp"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare 'prev' variable in some global class.
2. Declare it static
3. Use one instance of class for whole application
4. Store in Session
5. Store in Application

Answer (score 3):

Because in `ASP.NET` server side, on every call a new object of the page's class will be created. If you want to keep the value between calls, you can do one of this, based on your needs

1. Make the variable `static` : I do not recommend this approach, because when the application restarts, the last value will be lost, but in other 2 options there is solutions to keep the values over application restarts.
2. Use `Session` to store it : Use this if you need different values per user
3. Use `Application` to store it : Use this if you need one value for all users

Note: Don't forget to lock your variable on change, because of concurrency issues.

Comment: I also had a panel that forget its control at every call. How to make it static then?

Comment: Can you provide some code, or more information about it?

Comment: There should not be a problem with that code if you persist the value of `prev` across the page loads.

Comment: No, the panel forget its control everytime the c# code is called and overwrite its previous control with new one.

Answer (score 2):

Every time the page Post backs on Button Click event, your variable gets initialized again in asp.net.
To avoid this you can save the values of variable in one of the state management techniques.
example: Session

```
Session["prev"]="val";
```

In button click you can set this value by using

```
Session["prev"]="temp";
```

to recall this value you can use

```
string variable=Convert.ToString(Session["prev"]);
```

Hope this will help.